# How to get Fscore with compile

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics, tf.keras

to get Precision and Recall with model.compile we can do like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

model.compile( ..., metrics=['accuracy', 'Precision', 'Recall'])
```

so how to add  F1score to get all metrics(4)?

Answer (score 0):

Add `tfa.metrics.F1Score()` from the `tensorflow_addons` [package](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/metrics/F1Score).